# Google showing 'wrong' content of question in a search

Tags: discussion

I was looking for duplicates of why my name get's assigned to a different close reason (found a couple), but in the process I noticed something weird.

As I was searching, this was the result:

[image: Google search results]

There you can see **what I typed** and **the results** I got. Here is the catch: by navigating to the result marked in red, to my surprise, the page was **not what was presented** to me in the results. This is what I was redirected to:

[image: Loaded question]

As we can see, the result showed the question that as closed, having the result as a duplicate. Is this a concern? Case affirmative, can something be done about it?

I'm raising this discussion as this can be quite confusing to newcomers - specially since we could assume they wound't know how SO works. Is this google-related only? Do we have any control over this or is it by design somehow?

This seems wrong as the link (in green under the title) is not what the content is about.

Comment: I was confused as I tend to middle-mouse-click to open a new tab, but I couldn't find it. Then I clicked again just to see the title different from the google result.

Comment: so working as intended, even if a bit inconvenient at times. If SO auto redirected you to the dupe target, there would be no way for you to view the signpost, which wouldn't be good for moderation reasons.

Comment: Yeah, I can understand that @KevinB - thanks for pointing it out. It just, I don't know.. feels weird.

Answer (score 3):

Anonymous users get automatically redirected to the duplicate target.

If you were an anonymous user, you'd see the target; which is what google-bot saw. Since you were logged-in, you saw the dup-signpost.